# extract URL location from an xml link in java

Tags: java, xml, sitemap

I'm new in java and i have a link "https://moz.com/blog-sitemap.xml"  that has URLs ,i want to get them and save them in a string vector/array.

i tried this first to see how i'm going to get the links

```
URL robotFile = new URL("https://moz.com/blog-sitemap.xml");

    //read robot.txt line by line
    Scanner robotScanner = new Scanner(robotFile.openStream());
    while (robotScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(robotScanner.nextLine());
    }
```

this is the sample output 
[image]

my answer is ,is there a simple easier way to get these links instead of looping on each line checking if it contains "https" so i can extract the link from it ?

Comment: Please don't post the output as an image. Use plain text instead.

Comment: i thought it will be more clear as an image but okay @vanje

Comment: And yes there is an easier way: Parse the XML with an XML parser and extract the text contents of the loc nodes.

Comment: could u be more clear/detailed? @vanje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jsoup to do this more easly:

```
    List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://moz.com/blog-sitemap.xml").get();
    Elements urls = doc.getElementsByTag("loc");

    for (Element url : urls) {
        urlList.add(url.text());
    }
```